# HikariDataSource closes automatically when I query from it

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp

I have configured two database in my spring boot application as master and slave db. Whenever the application queries anything from the slave db, hikari pool is automatically closed and its throws error as

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  (137)    |> SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
[ http-nio-2100-exec-6 ] |ERROR|    o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  (142)    |> HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (REPORT_POOL) has been closed.
 [ http-nio-2100-exec-6 ] |ERROR|    c.n.c.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler  (485)   |> Critical Error: 
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

my configurations for db is as follows:

```
#Master Database
master.datasource.hikari.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/master_db
master.datasource.hikari.username=*****
master.datasource.hikari.password=*****
master.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=10
master.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=30
master.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
master.datasource.hikari.leakDetection=15000
master.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=25000
master.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=600000
master.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true

#Slave Database Read
report.datasource.hikari.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/slave_db
report.datasource.hikari.username=*****
report.datasource.hikari.password=*****
report.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=10
report.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=30
report.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
report.datasource.hikari.leakDetection=15000
report.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=20000
report.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=600000
report.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
```

I have configured two data sources as

```
@Bean
@Primary
@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSourceRouting routingDataSource = new DataSourceRouting();
    routingDataSource.initDatasource(masterDataSource(), readDataSource());
        return routingDataSource;
    }

    private DataSource masterDataSource() {
        HikariConfig master = new HikariConfig();
        master.setPoolName("MASTER_POOL");
        master.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.url", MASTER)));
        master.setUsername((env.getProperty(String.format("%s.username", MASTER))));
        master.setPassword((env.getProperty(String.format("%s.password", MASTER))));
        master.setMinimumIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.minimum-idle", MASTER))));
        master.setMaximumPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.maximum-pool-size", MASTER))));
        master.setConnectionTimeout(Long.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.connection-timeout", MASTER))));
        master.setIdleTimeout(Long.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.idle-timeout", MASTER))));
        master.setMaxLifetime(Long.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.max-lifetime", MASTER))));
        master.setLeakDetectionThreshold(Long.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.leakDetection", MASTER))));
        master.setAutoCommit(Boolean.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.auto-commit", MASTER))));
        masterDataSource = new HikariDataSource(master);
        return masterDataSource;
    }
    
    private DataSource readDataSource() {
        HikariConfig report = new HikariConfig();
        report.setPoolName("REPORT_POOL");
        report.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.url", REPORT)));
        report.setUsername((env.getProperty(String.format("%s.username", REPORT))));
        report.setPassword((env.getProperty(String.format("%s.password", REPORT))));
        report.setMinimumIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.minimum-idle", REPORT))));
        report.setMaximumPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.maximum-pool-size", REPORT))));
        report.setConnectionTimeout(Long.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.connection-timeout", REPORT))));
        report.setIdleTimeout(Long.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.idle-timeout", REPORT))));
        report.setMaxLifetime(Long.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.max-lifetime", REPORT))));
        report.setLeakDetectionThreshold(Long.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.leakDetection", REPORT))));
        report.setAutoCommit(Boolean.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.auto-commit", REPORT))));
        report.setReadOnly(Boolean.valueOf(env.getProperty(String.format("%s.read-only", REPORT))));

        try (HikariDataSource readDataSource = new HikariDataSource(report)) {
            readDataSource.getConnection();
            return readDataSource;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("\n\n******REPORT DB NOT FOUND, CONNECTED TO MASTER DB *******\n\n");
            return masterDataSource;
        }
    }
```

I have a DataSourceInterceptor for directing request to report db

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class DataSourceInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    protected static final String[] PREFIX_REPORT_DS = new String[] { "/admin/report/**", "/report/**" };

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        String uri = request.getRequestURI();

        if (StringUtil.isStartWith(uri, StringUtil.trimStricks(PREFIX_REPORT_DS))) {
            log.info("Redirect to Report Database for URL: {}", uri);
            DataSourceRouting.setReportRoute();
        }

        return true;

    }
}
```

And a DataSourceRouting for setting route to slave db

```
@Slf4j
public class DataSourceRouting extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    private static final ThreadLocal<Route> routeContext = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public enum Route {
        MASTER, REPORT
    }


    public static void setReportRoute() {
        routeContext.set(Route.REPORT);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return routeContext.get();
    }

    public void initDatasource(DataSource masterDs, DataSource reportDs) {
        log.info("Datasource routing...");
        Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceMap.put(Route.MASTER, masterDs);
        dataSourceMap.put(Route.REPORT, reportDs);
        this.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
        this.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDs);

    }
}
```

When the slave db is down or cannot be connnected during the application start-up, it gets connected to master db, then there is no issue in the application but when the slave db is connected, and the application tries to query from it, the above exception is thrown

Comment: Without seeing your code and how you are using things this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: I have added the configurations. Can it be of some help please?

Comment: The answer lies in your edit. Ofcourse it will throw the exception as nothing is there to query nor will it switch (your configuration is broken in that regard). If you have b oth the read and master available and read goes down. The connections remain. You haven't enabled connection validation while idle. which will check the connections and close them if broken and re-open new ones. If you don't it will keep broken connections open. ALso your `readDataSource` is broken as it will return something else if there is an error, instead you should stop starting imho.

Comment: Thank you!!
What changes should I do and how do I validate the connection while idle?

Comment: Make sure that your min/max are different and that you have set a decent number for the `validationTimeout` property.

Comment: i just changed minimum-idle, maximum-pool-size, max-lifetime of report db and added validation-timeout property on both but still it gives me same error

Comment: Then you are doing something that closes the datasource which you aren't showing here. It was already difficult from your snippets. Another thing is that your other datasources should be beans as well. Make the methods `public` and add `@Bean` to them so they get properly initialized. I would also suggest to use the Spring Boot documented way to configure multiple datasources. Another thing is you need to reset your threadlocal when the request is done, which is something you don't appear to do.

Comment: Upon further inspection the problem is your configuration, you are creating a datsource within a `try/resources` which will close the datasource. So as mentioned your confiugration is the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, as hinted already in the comments, your configuration. Whilst being overly extensive it is also wrong. What is wrong you are using a try-with-resources which will automatically close the resource after the block finishes. So in the end you are always ending up with a closed datasource. Regardless of the fact if it is or isn't connected.

I would strongly recommend following the [Spring Boot preferred way](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources) of configuring your datasources.

```java
@Configuration
public DatasourceConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSourceRouting routingDataSource = new DataSourceRouting();
    routingDataSource.initDatasource(masterDataSource(), readDataSource());
    return routingDataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  @ConfigurationProperties("master.datasource")
  public DataSourceProperties masterDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("report.datasource")
  public DataSourceProperties reportDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }
  
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("master.datasource.hikari")
  public HikariDataSource masterDataSource(DataSourceProperties masterDataSourceProperties) {
    return masterDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder()
      .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();  
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("report.datasource.hikari")
  public HikariDataSource masterDataSource(DataSourceProperties reportDataSourceProperties) {
    return reportDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder()
      .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();  
  }
}
```

The `url`, `username` and `password` property should be set on the datasource directly to prevent start failures.

```
#Master Database
master.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/master_db
master.datasource.username=*****
master.datasource.password=*****
master.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=10
master.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=30
master.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
master.datasource.hikari.leakDetection=15000
master.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=25000
master.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=600000
master.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true

#Slave Database Read
report.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/slave_db
report.datasource.username=*****
report.datasource.password=*****
report.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=10
report.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=30
report.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
report.datasource.hikari.leakDetection=15000
report.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=20000
report.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=600000
report.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
report.datasource.hikari.initializationFailTimeout=-1
```

To handle breaking connections make sure the min/max are different and that you set a reasonable `validationTimeout` for the validation. For the report database you could add the `initializationFailTimeout` and set a negative value. This will not lead to acquiring connections at startup but later on. This will allow you to even start with a broken reporting database, for which the connections, due to validation, later will be available.

Another thing that is wrong in your setup is that yo never reset the routing key, as it is stored in a `ThreadLocal` it will get reused eventually, as request handling threads are in a pool. You need to clear in the `afterCompletion` method of the `HandlerInterceptor`.

Comment: Thank you very much. The main culprit was the try-with-resources.